# Repeating same code block for creating different values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that basically calculates the missing values (x in this example) in multiple lists. 
These are the lists:

```
L11=[1,3,5,'x',8,10]
L12=['x',3,3,'x',6,0]
L21=[6,1,1,9,2,2]
L22=[1,1,1,'x','x','x']
```

For example, I'm using this code block to find the x values in L22:

```
#How to find x:
#1--> a= calculate the sum of integers in the list
#2--> b=calculate the average of them 
#3--> all values of x inside the list equal b

a22=L22.count('x')  
for i in range(len(L22)):
    if L22[i]=='x':
            x_L22=round((sum([int(k) for k in L22 if type(k)==int]))/(len(L22)-a22))
```

So we find x_L22=1 and the new L22 is:

```
x_L22=1
L22=[1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Now here is my question, I want to repeat this steps for all other lists without writing the same code. Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't just mean converting you're current solution into a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers focus on extracting your current code to a generic function which is useful but isn't neither sufficient nor necessary to apply the same piece of code on multiple input.

The only thing you need is to loop over your pieces of data :

```
L11=[1,3,5,'x',8,10]
L12=['x',3,3,'x',6,0]
L21=[6,1,1,9,2,2]
L22=[1,1,1,'x','x','x']

inputs = ( L11, L12, L21, L22 )

for input in inputs :
    # your 4 previous lines on code, modified to work
    # on the generic "input" instead of the specific "L22" 
    a=input.count('x')  
    for i in range(len(input)):
        if input[i]=='x':
             x=round((sum([int(k) for k in input if type(k)==int]))/(len(input)-a))
    # or if you've extracted the above code to a function,
    # just call it instead of using the above 4 lines of code.
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in a function like this:

```
def list_foo(list_):
    counted=list_.count('x')  
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        if list_[i]=='x':
            total=round((sum([int(k) for k in list_ if type(k)==int])) \ 
                  /(len(list_)-counted))
    return total
```

use it in your main loop

```
x_L22 = list_foo(L22)
```

or `x_L11 = list_foo(L11)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent use case for functions in Python

```
def get_filled_list(list_of_numbers):
    #How to find x:
    #1--> a= calculate the sum of integers in the list
    #2--> b=calculate the average of them 
    #3--> all values of x inside the list equal b

    new_list=list_of_numbers.count('x')  
    for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
        if list_of_numbers[i]=='x':
            list_of_numbers = round(
                (sum([int(k) 
                 for k in list_of_numbers if type(k)==int]))/
                (len(list_of_numbers)-new_list)
            ) 

A11 = get_filled_list(L11)
# ,..
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function that receives a list as an input and returns the same list with the `'x'` value replaced with a new value:

```
def calculateList(l):
    nrX=l.count('x')
    newList = []
    for elem in l:
        if elem == 'x':
            x = int(round((sum([int(k) for k in l if type(k)==int]))/(len(l)-nrX)))
            newList.append(x)
        else:
            newList.append(elem)
    return newList
```

You can then call this function on all the list you have:

```
newL = calculateList(L22)
print(newL)
```

Output is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Or if you prefer you can create a list containing all the lists you want to evaluate:

```
allLists = [L11, L12, L21, L22]
```

And then you iterate over this list:

```
for l in allLists:
    newL = calculateList(l)
    print(newL)
```

Output is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 5, 8, 10]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 0]
[6, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```